# can connect to mysql with java application but cannot with spring mvc

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am trying to learn Spring MVC.I have a registration form which I am trying to persist. I have MySQL as backend.I have a test java application which is able to connect to MySQL and insert into table. But the same thing does not work for the web application. I am using Eclipse as IDE and Maven for build and tomcat as webserver.

Datasource file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chorechart" />  
<property name="username" value="username" />  
<property name="password" value="password*" />  
</bean>
```

DAO

```
package com.chorechart.dao.impl;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.chorechart.dao.RegisterDAO;
import com.chorechart.model.Register;

@Service("registerDAO")
public class JdbcRegisterDAO implements RegisterDAO{
private DataSource dataSource;


public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Override
public void insertUser(Register registerUser) {
    String sql = "Insert into register"+" 
(FirstName,LastName,Email_username,password)"
            + "values(?,?,?,?)";

    );
    try {
        System.out.println("DataSourrce"+dataSource);
        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        System.out.println("coonection"+conn);
        PreparedStatement ps= conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,registerUser.getFirstName());
        ps.setString(2,registerUser.getLastName());
        ps.setString(3, registerUser.getEmail_username());
        ps.setString(4, registerUser.getPassword());
        int x = ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.print("JDBCRegisterDao");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}

@Override
public Register findUser(String userName, String userPwd) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: What does cannot connect mean? Do you get an error? If so, post it.

Comment: add some spaces into your sql

Comment: Also, post the java code that works.

Comment: Thanks Thom, Here is the error   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server.)